# Headsup Notification Play Sound Over Other Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

I currently have a notification that is set as a headsup notification by having it play a sound and have max priority. I build it like this:

```
builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX).setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.alarm_text))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_24dp)
                .setSound(alarm_sound, attributes);
Notification notif = builder.build();

notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
```

The problem is that if a text comes in while this notification is present (the notification is important, as it is attached to a wake up alarm) the text message sound completely stops the rest of the sound being played. Additionally my notification disappears before the text message notification which appears on top, so I never get to actually see my notification (which has buttons like dismiss alarm attached).